# javascript regular expression to match 2 parts of url (menu & submenu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'd like to add an "active" class to the menu item that is active.

That works fine like so:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");

$('.menu li a').each(function(){
        var hreflink = $(this).attr("href");

        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
});
```

I also have a 2nd menu on the page (a submenu, but not located near the main menu), with a list of links of the children of that page, and I would like to also add an "active" class to the submenu also (but also the the main menu at the same time)

So basically for example, when I'm on this page:

```
www.website.com/shops/cds
```

- I want to add the active class to "shops" in the main menu (li item)
- I want to add the active class to "cds" in the submenu (li item)

At the moment the regex above will only work for either the main menu, and if I'm on a sub-page (a child page), it will work for the submenu, but not for both at the same time.

Can someone please help me? ;-)

Many thanks in advance!!

Kind regards
Ben

Comment: Have you thought about using `location.pathname` to obtain `/shops/cds` and then just splitting by `/`?

Comment: Note: using strict mode will reveal that `urlRegExp` is an implicit global variable because of the semicolon instead of a comma at the end of the previous line, which you probably didn't intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a site called http://www.regexr.com/ for all my JS Regexing.

This Regex gets your components:

```
/\/(([a-z])+)/ig
```

Here is a sample program for you:

```js
var url = 'www.website.com/shops/cds'
var reg = /\/(([a-z])+)/ig

var test = $('#test')

var match = reg.exec(url);
while (match != null) {
  test.append('<div>' + match[1] + '</div>')
  match = reg.exec(url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Test for: www.website.com/shops/cds
</div>
<div id="test">
  
</div>
```

Comment: what I am seeing now though is when I'm on a root page, all the menu items become active, any ideas? :-)

for example:

http://www.website.com (the all the menu icons become active)

Comment: Hey, sorry, just saw you commented.  Now that I'm re-reading your question, I think you might need to add a special case for if the current page is the root or "/" because that will always match with that REGEX.  I think it would be easier to just add an "if/else"